# How do I mock HTTPSClient post service

Tags: http, post, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I want to mock the following line of code:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = client.callPostService(url, dto, new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>(){});
```

Attempt

```
@Test
public void testFunction{
    HTTPSClient client = Mockito.mock(HTTPSClient.class);
    Mockito.when(client.callPostService(any(String.class),any(Dto.class), new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>{}))
}
```

I get errors regarding the parameters I have placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mix Mockito's argument matchers (like any(), eq() etc.) and the real objects while configuring behavior for a mock.

So, in your case the next would be correct:

```
Mockito.when(client.callPostService(any(String.class),any(Dto.class), Mockito.any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class))).thenReturn(...)
```

or (since Java 8):

```
Mockito.when(client.callPostService(any(String.class),any(Dto.class), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(...)
```

The latter also doesn't raise the compiler warning about the unchecked cast of generic type because of enhanced type inference.